# Declare a buffer for an in-memory Bitmap

Tags: c++, c, arrays, data-structures, buffer

I'm designing a graphics library which only works with a **bitmap** that is **stored in memory**.

Since a bitmap is 2-dimensional (x and y or columns and rows), i can use a 2-dimensional array.

```
//PIXEL_BIT is a user defined type to store RGB values of a single pixel
PIXEL_BIT buffer[1366][768];
```

From my understanding, C++ doesn't play nice with two dimensional arrays. Especially when it comes to dynamic 2-d arrays. So I believe, 2-dimensional arrays are not so cool to use as a buffer (or an in memory bitmap).

Another method to declare a buffer would be:

```
PIXEL_BIT *buffer = new PIXEL_BIT[1366 * 768];
```

I think this method is more efficient. So my question is, If you were to store a bitmap in memory what kind of a buffer would you use ? What's the best way to store a bitmap in memory *(I think a block of memory that can be randomly accessed)* ?

[Edit]
I do understand what the heap and the stack are. And you should probably see this question:
[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: in which way doesn't C++ play well with arrays? I'd try both: measure the run times and compare

Comment: @jev I meant two-dimensional arrays doesn't fit the situation and i stated that one dimensional arrays would be more efficient than two-dimensional arrays. Since the computer memory is linear and a 2-d array us just an abstraction, it would be not be more efficient to use 2-d arrays than single dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Two dimensional array creates an array of pointers to plain arrays. This would cause some complications in memory management and/or streaming of such arrays. I'd prefer doing it the second way, creating one dimensional array, and using a few macros or inline functions to access elements. In fact, it would be better to create a structure, that has members to specify "width" and "heights" of buffer.

```
struct PIXEL_BIT_MAP {
PIXEL_BIT *buffer;
size_t height;
size_t width;
}
```

Comment: Yes 2d arrays are an array of pointers to arrays. And This is exactly what I thought.

Comment: @wirm *"Two dimensional array creates an array of pointers to plain arrays."*. Not necessarily true, `PIXEL_BIT buffer[1366][768];` creates *array of arrays*. There are no pointers involved.

Comment: @user694733    first of all, array is a pointer, unless it is statically allocated, which is not our case. If we create two dimensional dynamic array, then it will be `PIXEL_BIT **array;`

Comment: @wirm Both code lines OP posted do not have any array of pointers. Only pointer is on his second line `PIXEL_BIT *buffer`. [Array is **not** a pointer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/694733).

Answer (score 0):

The first way (`PIXEL_BIT buffer[1366][768];`) allocates memory on stack, which means after your current function returns, that block of memory becomes unusable.

You should allocate memory on heap to store bitmaps, using either `new` operator or `malloc()`. There is no obvious difference between these two methods, and both allocate "a block of memory that can be randomly accessed".

Comment: @DavidSebastian You probably don't want to use the dynamic 2D array in that answer. It is better to store a whole bitmap in a block of continuous memory instead of storing it line by line. You won't lose any performance or functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two easy ways to make a 2d array. You can wrap the latter in a nice class, so you don't have to provide the index calculation each time. I would think that the second is faster, because all the data is nearby in memory.

```
vector<vector<T>> myvec(Y, vector<T>(X));
myvec[y][x] = ...;

vector<T> myvec(X * Y);
myvec(y * X + x) = ...;
```